# Help applying two different styles to Ruby on Rails pluralize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, css-selectors

How do I apply two different styles to the "vote" text and the number output from this RoR code:

```
<%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'Vote' %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to style the pluralized word, I would just suggest doing the following:

```
<%= video.vote_sum %>
<div class="style-word">
<% word = "Vote" %>
<% if video.vote_sum > 1 %>
  <%= word.pluralize %>
<% else %>
  <%= word %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

(Sorry about all the <% %>, I'm so used to HAML now, I don't do erb anymore).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Note that I want to apply styling to the number that is different from the "vote" text.

Comment: btw @Mike, I also have some jQuery code for updating the vote_sum with ajax and it needs to be styled as well: `$('#vote_display').html("<p id='votes'><%= escape_javascript pluralize(@video.vote_sum, 'Vote') %></p>")`  I tried the same thing but it doesn't work :/

Comment: any thoughts on how the jQuery code should be structured to support the styling, or should it be the same thing?

Comment: It should be the same thing, so because of this you may want to factor out the vote display into a partial( to reduce duplication)

Comment: I'm having a problem though. If I do the exact same thing in the create.js.erb file, it doesn't have access to the variable `video`. If i change `video` to `@video`, then the template is rendered according to my logs, but the vote count from the user's perspective doesn't seem to change. It works after a page refresh, which means the votes are being inserted and the logic is working fine, so there must be something wrong with the AJAX rendering. Strange..

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div class="<%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'number' %>">
  <%= video.vote_sum %>
</div>
<div class="<%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'vote' %>">
  <%= pluralize video.vote_sum, 'Vote' %>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.vote{# some style code here!}
.votes{# some style code here!}
.number{# some style code here!}
.numbers{# some style code here!}
```

Comment: +1, but it'll be little cleaner: `<div class="<%= votes = pluralize( video.vote_sum, 'Vote' ) %>"><%= votes %></div>`

Comment: I'm confused. What exactly does this do? Does this apply different styles whether it's plural or singular? Because I want to apply different styles to the number and the text. For example< `<div class='number'>10</div><div class='text'>Votes</div>`

Comment: @fl00r - Thanks for the edit and yes it is cleaner, but it adds to your typing and some more chars in code.                       @Justin - you can do the same thing for your number at the place of 'Vote' in "<% pluralize video.vote_sum, 'Vote' %> I have edited my answer have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= pluralize video.vote_sum, '<span class="some_other_class">Vote</span>', '<span class="some_other_class">Votes</span>' %>
```

Comment: thanks. How would I get vote on the next line? Would I have to use <br /> or would wrapping it in a div be sufficient?

Comment: You could use any block element instead (like `div`) or use CSS to style the `span` as a block element.

Comment: Inline (example): `<span style='display:block'>Vote</span>`

Comment: @Justin Meltzer: Try doing as suggested: use a `div` instead of a `span` (or apply `display: block` as a rule for that span).

Comment: Oh ok, so a div would do this?

Comment: I just realized, ActionView won't be able to pluralize an HTML string like that :) You'll have to add a custom plural string as well (see my updated code).

Comment: Oh, I see.. just tried it on a test Rails app, and it looks like the HTML is being escaped. Hmm.. not sure how to get around this, but unfortunately I need to get to bed.. I'll get back to you on this sometime tomorrow if no one else figures it out by then :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact situation and chose to extend the `pluralize` method in `application_helper.rb`

```
def pluralize(count, singular, plural = nil)
  count, counted = super.split(' ', 2)
  [content_tag(:span, count, class: 'count'),content_tag(:span, counted, class: 'counted')].join(' ').html_safe
end
```

`pluralize(2, "Thing")` will now output something like `<span class="count">1</span> <span class="counted">Things</span>`